# Custom Cordova Plugin

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I'm trying to write a custom plugin for Cordova 2.0.0.
The custom plugin that I want to make has to get the WP accent color, so I can use it in the app Style.

But I can't manage to make it work properly and can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

**Index.js**

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    click();
}
function click() {
    navigator.notification.alert(callback, callback, "text", "button");
    window.getAccentColor();
}
```

**GetTheme.cs**

```
namespace Cordova.Extension.Commands
 {
   // Use the phonegap base class
   public class GetTheme : BaseCommand 
   {
     public void Get()
     {
         Color currentColorHex = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
         var result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, currentColorHex.ToString());
         DispatchCommandResult(result);
     }
   }
 }
```

**GetTheme.js**

```
window.getAccentColor = function () {
    cordova.exec(win, error, "GetTheme", "Get");
}

function win(result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("2");
};


function error() {
}
```

There a some things a bit strange that I've noticed.
With the notification pop-up on the click action "2" is written in the output. But without it doesn't output anything.

In both cases `result` from the `win` function is still empty and doesn't output anything.

All the *.js files are included in the `index.html` file in the head section.
The callback method from the notification is defined but it does nothing.

I've also tried with the `WP7CordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Cordova documentation page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html),

```
// all JS callable plugin methods MUST have this signature!
// public, returning void, 1 argument that is a string
```

So, in your GetTheme.cs, change

```
     public void Get()
```

into

```
     public void Get(string options)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't help. I removed some useless test code, and I noticed that my plugin isn't even called.

Answer (score 0):

finding the answers to these questions will help you (and us) understand why your plugin is not being called....

- Is onDeviceReady being called?
- Is click being called?
- This looks foreign to me "navigator.notification.alert(callback,
  callback, "text", "button");" what is that supposed to do
- Does the output window of VS.NET show any JS errors that are
  preventing the rest of your js from executing?

Comment: To answer your questions:
-onDeviceReady is called
-click is called
-`navigator.notification.alert()` shows a WP7 style confirmation.
-no errors shown in VS.NET or JS
I've tried with different locations for the plugin and still nothing. I've managed to make it work by editing and existing plugin. There were a lot of things different from example on the PhoneGap site.

Comment: i have seen my plugin NOT get called if there is a namespace issue in the plugin name, i.e. the 3rd argument of cordova exec is wrong.  I have also seen my plugin NOT Get called if there is NO value or bad values supplied for the options argument (the 5th argument) of cordova exec.

Answer (score 0):

The C# part of this looks identical to my plugin, so I think it's fine.

The javascript part is different however.  Here's my complete plugin.js (Really simple plugin which fires up the create-new-sms task on Windows Phone, as it doesn't respond to navigation to sms: scheme's like iOS and Android)

```
function SMSComposer() {
    this.resultCallback = null;
}

SMSComposer.prototype.showSMSComposer = function (toRecipients, body) {

    var args = {};
    var smsComposerOk = function () { console.log("SMSComposer Called OK"); };
    var smsComposerError = function (error) { console.log("SMSComposer error:" + error); };
    if (toRecipients) {
        args.toRecipients = toRecipients;
    }

    if (body) {
        args.body = body;
    }

    Cordova.exec(smsComposerOk, smsComposerError, "SendSMS", "send", args);
};

SMSComposer.install = function () {
    console.log("SMSComposer being installed");
    if (!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }
    window.plugins.SMSComposer = new SMSComposer();

    return window.plugins.SMSComposer;
};
```

and in my onDeviceReady() I have.....

```
    if (window.device && window.device.platform == "WinCE") {
        SMSComposer.install();
    }
```

I'm using Cordova 2.0.
Make sure you are checking the console for log messages.  If Cordova fails somewhere, something is logged.